# Different output on Geeks for Geeks IDE and my PyCharm IDE. What's the problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Python code to retrieving web pages as file. I wrote this program:

```
import urllib.request,urllib.parse,urllib.error

fhand = urllib.request.urlopen('http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt')

for line in fhand:
    print(line.decode().strip())
```

It's been executed successfully and I got my result.
[image: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Mm95ZYnRzt/]

I get the following error in **PyCharm**:

```
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ashik/PycharmProjects/RawCodes/web_access.py", line 2, in <module>
    import urllib.request,urllib.parse,urllib.error
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.parser'; 'email' is not a package

Process finished with exit code 1
```

*Can anyone solve this problem and let me know why this happens?*

Comment: Are you sure the required modules are installed?

Comment: [This](https://python-forum.io/Thread-A-trouble-with-requests) looks similar. Do you have a file named 'email.py'?

Comment: Yes, obviously. Otherwise, I would get a suggestion there to improve that modules.

Comment: The error is happening when importing the package

Comment: Yes,I have a file of that name. 'email.py'

Comment: Rename it or move it elsewhere. This is causing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error appears upon importing, so you probably don't have all the packages installed or they are not installed properly.

Try

```
pip install urllib
```

in case the problem appears in your system.

Furthermore, as mentioned in the comments, if you have a python file in the same folder named after one of the used modules or named after one of the modules those modules use, this file is used at the place of those modules. If that is the case you have to rename this file or move it. For more information about this error check chapter 6.1.2 from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

In case the error appears in geek IDE , it means that they don't have this module installed. In the latter case, I don't think that you can do something about it.

Comment: Thanks.
I did such a foolish mistake before, I need to concentrate more on such silly matters.

Comment: It's normal, it's not something you could have guessed :)